# Image or sprites sometimes doesn't show while compile xCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I got a problem with my simple game. Every picture as Player, background, floor, coins, Score Text etc are set as a "add child" in function `didMoveToView`. It looks like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    balon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: balon.size.width/2)
    balon.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    balon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physics.Balon
    balon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physics.Moneta
    balon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physics.None
    balon.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true





    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self





     /////////////////// MOVE COINS ///////////////////////////////////////


    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addCoin),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
            ])
        ))


    /////////////////// MOVE BOMB ///////////////////////////////////////



    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addBomb),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
            ])
        ))








    self.backround.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.runningBar.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)

    self.runningBar.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))


    self.orginalBarPosition = self.runningBar.position.x

    self.MaxBarPos = self.runningBar.size.width - self.frame.size.width

    self.MaxBarPos *= -1


    self.balonBaseLine = self.runningBar.position.y + (self.runningBar.size.height/2) + (self.balon.size.height/2)
    self.balon.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - self.balon.size.width * 2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))



    self.backround.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

    self.originalBackgroundPosition = self.backround.position.x

    self.maxBackgroundPosition = self.backround.size.width - self.frame.size.width * 1.11

    self.maxBackgroundPosition *= -1


    scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 16
    scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor();
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)


    addChild(scoreLabel)

    addChild(backround)

    addChild(runningBar)

    addChild(balon) }
```

There is a problem.. Sometimes everything works fine but usually when I'm running my program something will not shows up. For example background and coins shows up but the player (Balon) doesn't, or sometimes Coins and Bombs shows up but the floor(movingBar) doesn't.
RunningBar is moving, it's declared in override func update(currentTime: `NSTimeInterval`) just like moving background (it's a sky). I don't understand why sometimes everything is OK and mostly is not OK... 
I have no errors while compiling my project. 
I would really like to understand what's wrong with this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you have your zPositions set up correctly?

Comment: I think so. Did You see any mistake? But if there would be something wrong then The game wouldn't run Perfectly (sometimes..)

Comment: @Matt199 you should add zPosition to all of your nodes

Comment: I had a similar issue a long time ago where I thought my nodes were disappearing and reappearing but really they were just going behind my background node in zPosition. Try setting background.zPosition = 0 and all other nodes.zPosition greater than 0.

Comment: Yes... Thank you guys so so much! That was The problem! Thank you!